# Prove that $\exists c \in [a,b] \: \text{s.c}\: f(x)-f(a)- \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)=\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{2}f''(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

> Given function $f$ differentiable on $[a,b]$, and has derivative $f''(x)$ on $[a,b]$, prove that for all $x\in[a,b]$, we have at least one $c\in[a,b]$ such that $$f(x)-f(a)- \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)=\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{2}f''(c)$$

I tried using Rolle theorem to no avail, but I think I will need to derive something else from here. If I have $$\theta(x)=f(x)-f(a)- \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)-\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{2}f''(c)$$
$$\longrightarrow \theta'(x)=f'(x)- \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-\lambda \left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\right), \lambda = f''(c)$$ Of which still nothing came across my mind. Trying to rearrange gives
$$\underbrace{\left[\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right]}_{(I)}-\underbrace{\left[\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right]}_{(II)}=\frac{(x-b)}{2}f''(x)$$
of which I see that $(I)\rightarrow f'(c_1)$ for $c_1\in [a,x]$ and $(II)=f(c_2)$ for $c_2 \in [a,b]$. But still, there are no clue to proceed.

My request here is to trying to find a way to resolve this problem, while also trying to understand the notion of what the proof really means,and what exactly is being examined here. So:

- How can I prove the above results?
- What is the meaning of the expressions and what is happening inside?
- What is (potentially) the geometrical intepretation and representation of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Taylor formula at $x,$ $a<x<b,$ we get
$$ f(a)=f(x)-f'(x)(x-a)+{1\over 2}f''(d_1)(x-a)^2\\
f(b)=f(x)+f'(x)(b-x)+{1\over 2}f''(d_2)(b-x)^2$$
for some $a<d_1<x<d_2<b.$ We subtract $f(x)$ in both identities, next divide the first equality by $x-a$ and the second one by $b-x,$ and finally add them. We  obtain
$${f(b)-f(x)\over b-x} -{f(x)-f(a)\over x-a}={1\over 2}[f''(d_1)(x-a)+f''(d_2)(b-x)]$$
The quantity $${x-a\over b-a}f''(d_1)+{b-x\over b-a}f''(d_2)$$ is a convex combination of $f''(d_1)$ and $f''(d_2).$ As $f''$ satisfies the Darboux property we get
$${f(b)-f(x)\over b-x} -{f(x)-f(a)\over x-a}={1\over 2}(b-a)f''(c)$$ for some $d_1<c<d_2.$ The last equation is equivalent to the one in OP.

Comment: I am quite clueless about Darboux property here, can you state more details about that, please? I am quite curious about that.

Comment: If a function $f$ is twice differentiable then $f''$ satisfies the Darboux property. This is obvious if $f''$ is continuous. For $d_1<d_2$ if $f''(d_1)=f''(d_2),$ then  $${x-a\over b-a}f''(d_1)+{b-x\over b-a}f''(d_2)=f''(d_1)$$ Hence we can take $c=d_1.$ If $f''(d_1)\neq f''(d_2),$ then one of the value is larger than the other. WLOG let $f''(d_1)<f''(d_2).$ Then $$f''(d_1)<{x-a\over b-a}f''(d_1)+{b-x\over b-a}f''(d_2)<f''(d_2)$$ By the Darbiux property of $f''$  the value inside is equal $f''(c)$ for some $d_1<c<d_2.$

Comment: A good explaination I must say. Thank you very much.